# Correct way to write MySql Query for find certain values in one field and replace another fields value

Tags: mysql

I am no expert on MySQL, but I want to do a query that finds a set of records, based on a list of policynameID's and changes another field for that record set.

I have done the query like this, but am not sure this is the right way.  Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this?  Can I just do a list of policynameID numbers separated by commas?  Any help appreciated.

UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='473';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='690';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='746';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='649';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='798';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='570';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='481';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='541';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='802';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='578';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='726';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='592';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='676';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='465';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='766';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='151';
UPDATE `policyname` SET `StarRating_StarRatingID`=['1'] WHERE `PolicyNameID`='149';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *just* use a single query with `IN` clause, e.g.:

```
UPDATE policyname 
SET StarRating_StarRatingID='1' 
WHERE PolicyNameID IN ('473', '690', '746'...);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks Darshan for the lightning reply!  Thats just what I needed to know.